# Fill a hashmap in superclass from subclass constructor in Java

Tags: java, javafx, subclass, abstract, superclass

I have an abstract superclass that is set up like this in JavaFX:

```
abstract class View {
protected static HashMap<String, View> viewMap;
View(){
    viewMap = new HashMap<String, View>();
}
public static void addMap(String key, View value){
    viewMap.put(key, value);
}
```

This super class includes the method:

```
public static VBox goToView (final String view){
    return viewMap.get(view).getView();
}
```

Then I have some subclasses that represents scenes I want to load set up like this:

```
public class SceneA extends View {

private static String title;

public ViewA() {

    title = "TitleA";

    super.addMap(title, this);
}

public VBox getPane(){
      //code that will load for this scene
}
```

Subsequent subclass scenes are set up the same way.
Then in the main program I call like this:

```
public class OrganizationMenu {

private Stage organization;
private static BorderPane border;

public OrganizationMenu() {

    stage = new Stage();

    border = new BorderPane();
    border.setCenter(View.goToView(ViewA.getTitle()));
```

This works great for the first view, but any subsequent views aren't being added to the HashMap at the superclass.  I can't understand why.  Even if I save the ViewA code as ViewB, just changing the references, it doesn't fill the map.  Why would this work for one and not additional views?

Comment: `View(){ viewMap = new HashMap<String, View>(); }` you are creating a new `Map` every time you are instanciating `View` or one of its sub-classes.

Comment: initializing static fields from instance methods or constructors is a huge design small. A static variable is shared by ALL instances of the class. In fact, non-final static variables are, by themselves, a design smell.

Comment: thank you... this makes perfect sense... but i'm kind of new so sometimes these things don't jump out right away ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understood is you have an Abstract class View, this class contains a static HashMap viewMap. This abstract class has some subclasses and each time a subclass is instantiated, you want that subclass get added to the viewMap object of super class.

If i am right then the constructor in the super class View is the problem. Everytime a subclass gets instantiated, the viewMap is pointing to a new HaspMap object as the constructor of subClass

Please remove the constructor code and try like this:

```
abstract class View {

protected static HashMap<String, View> viewMap = new HashMap<String, View>();

public static void addMap(String key, View value) {
    viewMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Hope this works.